# ¿Como mostrar los años en un select?

Tags: php, html5

Tengo este código,pero no me funciona.Intente por mi mismo hacerlo.Por favor díganme como hago para que me muestre los años en una lista desplegable desde el año 1945 hasta el año actual.

```
      <select name="year">

                <option value="0">Año</option>

                <?php 
                   $year = date("Y");
                     for ($i= 1945; $i < $year+1 ; $i++) { 

                     echo'<option VALUE="'+$i+'">'+$i+'</option>';

                         }

                    ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <option value="0">Año</option>

            <?php 
               $year = date("Y");
                 for ($i= 1945; $i < $year ; $i++) { //quitarle el +1 Aver ?

                 echo'<option VALUE="'+$i+'">'+$i+'</option>';

                     }

                ?>
</select>
```

**O si no Prueba con este codigo**

```
                    <select name="year">
                      <option value="0">Año</option>
                      <?php  for($i=1990;$i<=2020;$i++) { echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>"; } ?>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Esta igual.No funciona

Comment: Espera un momento

Comment: si te funciona solo faltaria susplantar 2020 por el año actual . que te da date("Y")

Comment: así lo hice!cambie el 2020 por la variable en la que guardo el año actual y funciono?Ahora bien como hago para que que me salga el año actual de primero?

Comment: @Luis Para que te salga el año actual de primero, si quieres seguir viendo Año y a continuación el año actual, pones después de esto: `<option value="0">Año</option>` otra option con el año actual, antes de empezar el bucle for, algo así: `<?php echo '<option value=".$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';` Si no quieres que ponga primero Año sino simplemente el año actual, borras: `<option value="0">Año</option>` y dejas lo anterior.

Answer (score 1):

**Lo mas correcto es asi**

```
<?php
    echo "<select name='ano'>";
        for($i=1970;$i<=date("Y");$i++)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Pruebalo y me avisas si te funciono

Comment: Te funciono amigo ?

Comment: Gamez No,pero esta bin lo dejare asi como estaba

Comment: ok. mañana te ayudo mejor porque estoy con la table y no puedo ejecutar codigos, cuenta con eso mañana

Comment: el problema esta con el date, ejecutalo aparte a ver que año te muestra

Comment: dale un echo  date("Y"); aver

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, cambia la porción de código donde imprimes mediante PHP tus :

```
echo'<option value="$i">' . $i . '</option>';
```

En PHP para concatenar un String se utiliza el signo de puntuación **.** y no el signo más **+**

Answer (score 0):

*Tal vez no estas concatenando bien los años en el "echo" prueba con el siguiente codigo*

```
<select name="year">
  <option value="0" selected>0</option>
  <?php $year = date("Y");
        for ($i=1945; $i<=$year; $i++){
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
  ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Podrías añadir qué cambios has hecho y qué error corrigen respecto al autor. Recuerda que es mejor enseñar a pescar que regalar peces.